# Laravel 6 - Named route in blade not allowing special characters or capital letters in parameters

Tags: laravel

I've recently upgraded to laravel 6 and I've noticed an odd bug. Some of my routes in my blade templates stopped working.

Take this route for example:

```
Route::post('/create-save-folder/', [
    'uses' => 'SaveFolderController@createSaveFolder',
    'as' => 'create.save.folder',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

In blade this used to work just fine back in laravel 5.8:

```
<a href="{{ route('get.save.folder', ['ID' => $folder->ID, 'URL_title' => $folder->URL_title]) }}">
```

However now it gives me the error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: get.save.folder] [URI:
> save-folder/{ID}/{URL_title}]. (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\MC\resources\views\partials\user_sidebar_block.blade.php)

So I did some debugging. If I change the parameters to random strings, like so:

```
<a href="{{ route('get.save.folder', ['ID' => 'test', 'URL_title' => 'test']) }}">
```

that works fine.

So after more debugging I tried changing '$folder->ID' to '$folder->id' in the first parameter.

That ended up working. Which is really weird because if I write something like this in blade:

```
<p>URL TITLE:{{$folder->URL_title}}</p>
<p>ID:{{$folder->ID}}</p>
```

it will return the proper results. So that works fine for 'id', but 'URL_title' is still giving me trouble because it has an underscore. So unless I switch my database column to 'urltitle' instead of 'URL_title', I don't know how I'm going to get this route to work.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with my blade files when upgrading but not exactly the same as yours.

Doing `php artisan view:clear` did the trick for me.

Comment: Didn't do anything. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried `dd($folder)` to see if the `URL_title` exists?